# Is this simple has-member SFINAE technique compliant?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, language-lawyer, sfinae

I'm using a simple (not particularly new) technique to check for the existence of a class member of a particular name and type.
The following code compiles fine in Clang, but MSVC reports that the static_assert failed.

```
template<typename T, T m>
struct SfinaeNonType
{
    typedef void Type;
};

struct Member
{
};

template<typename C, typename U = void>
struct HasMember
{
    static const bool RESULT = false;
};

template<typename C>
struct HasMember<C, typename SfinaeNonType<Member C::*, &C::member>::Type>
{
    static const bool RESULT = true;
};

struct A
{
    Member member;
};

static_assert(HasMember<A>::RESULT, ""); // msvc rejects
```

Is there anything non-compliant about this code, or is this simply a bug in MSVC?

If it's a bug, is there a simple workaround?

Curiously, MSVC is happy with (otherwise identical code) checking for the existence of a member function rather than a data member:

```
template<typename T, T m>
struct SfinaeNonType
{
    typedef void Type;
};

struct Member
{
};

template<typename C, typename U = void>
struct HasMember
{
    static const bool RESULT = false;
};

template<typename C>
struct HasMember<C, typename SfinaeNonType<Member (C::*)(), &C::member>::Type>
{
    static const bool RESULT = true;
};

struct A
{
    Member member();
};

static_assert(HasMember<A>::RESULT, ""); // msvc accepts
```

Comment: Which version of MSVC?

Comment: @DyP Tested in both VS2010 and VS2012.